# Pakistani national living in France, travelling to UK

Tags: visas, uk, pakistani-citizens, french-residents

Do I need a visa for the UK to visit a family member... I'm a Pakistani national living in France with my partner and have a residence permit for France?

Comment: Is your permit an Article 10 or 20 residence card https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card?

Answer (score 1):

[You don't need a visa](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm#residence-card-yes-schengen-to-non-schengen-1) if you have a residence card as an EU national family member issued by an EU country other than the country your EU spouse is a national of.

Comment: We are a site where 'I believe' is not good enough. Please quote the relevant part out of the site you link to (and leave the link in) so people who read this can be sure about it.

Comment: (+1) I don't understand the hostility, especially towards a new user. We have many answers with less evidence, the point made in this one is pretty basic and easy to verify using the link. It's important to note however that for any other French residence title, a visa can be required to visit the UK.

Comment: It is not sufficient simply to "have a residence card as an EU national family member issued by an EU country other than the country your EU spouse is a national of"; it is also necessary for the EU family member to accompany the non-EU family member or to be present in the UK when the non-EU family member arrives.  This is not immediately obvious from the page you link to, although a clue is that the title of its first section is "Travelling in the EU with your non-EU family members."

Comment: Also see [Entering the UK as the holder of an Article 10 or 20 residence card](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card).  This is expected to change after the end of the transition period for the UK's withdrawal from the European Union.  The transition period is expected to end at the end of 2020.

Comment: Also the main reason to quote relevant parts of linked pages is that links eventually stop working.  If there is no quoted material, future readers will not know the basis for the answer.  Furthermore, quoted material makes it possible to use a search engine to find pages that have been moved, making it much easier to restore broken links.

Comment: @Relaxed, my comment was not meant as hostility against a new user but a request to bring the answer up to the standard everybody is asked to maintain here. And I do ask it from everybody, new or long term users, if the answer is not containing quotes and is started by words as 'I believe'.